# [WSO2]New feature : Support X-Forwarded-For HTTP extension header

Tags: http-headers, wso2, wso2-esb

could someone explain me what the new WSO2 ESB feature "Support X-Forwarded-For HTTP extension header" exactly is and how to use it?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

X-Forwarded-For is used by Proxies and some Firewalls and the like to hand the original IP to the server. Otherwise the server only sees the IP of the Proxy/Firewall (which may in case of a Firewall be constant for every request, which is of course bad for many web applications which rely on IP-based user detection code).

From [Wikipedia on XFF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For):

> The X-Forwarded-For (XFF) HTTP header field is a de facto standard for
>   identifying the originating IP address of a client connecting to a web
>   server through an HTTP proxy or load balancer. This is an HTTP request
>   header which was introduced by the Squid caching proxy server's
>   developers. An effort has been started at IETF for standardizing the
>   Forwarded-For HTTP header.
>
> In this context, the caching servers are most often those of large
>   ISPs who either encourage or force their users to use proxy servers
>   for access to the World Wide Web, something which is often done to
>   reduce external bandwidth through caching. In some cases, these proxy
>   servers are transparent proxies, and the user may be unaware that they
>   are using them.

Comment: Thank you Jonas
my question was not clear : how do i get the x-forwarded-for value in wso2 esb?

Comment: <log>
            <property name="xforward-header" expression="$trp:X-Forwarded-For"/>
 </log>